# It's possible to inject text in the not-found message

Tags: .htaccess, security, drupal, drupal-7

It's possible to inject text in the not-found message in order to trick the user to make him visit website or do something an attacker might be interested in.

It is returning the user input in the not-found message body. This can be misused in a number of ways.

1. Attacker injecting text can redirect users to malicious sites.
2. Attacker injecting text can prompt users with false messages.

Proof Of Concept:

```
https://drupal7.example/.htcaccess/***Attention!***%2f../Site%20has%20been%20replace%20by%20a%20new%20one%20https://www.google.com%20so%20go%20to%20the%20new%20one%20since%20this%20one
```

In some other cases, like

```
https://drupal7.example/htaccess // without dot for example
```

everything's fine and

```
# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.                                                                                                               
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

in .htaccess file working as expected and Drupal handle all 404 errors.

Any idea how to fix this and make Drupal handle all 404 errors including the one from example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is due to the presence of `%2F` (encoded slash `/`) in URL.

Apache uses the [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive to determine whether encoded path separators in URLs are allowed to be passed through. Default is `Off`, in which case getting an Apache 404 instead of a Drupal 404 is "normal" when you have `%2f` in URL :

> The AllowEncodedSlashes directive allows URLs which contain encoded path
> separators (%2F for / and additionally %5C for \ on accordant systems)
> to be used in the path info.
>
> - Off : such URLs are refused with a 404 (Not
>   found) error.
> - On : such URLs are accepted, and encoded slashes are
>   decoded like all other encoded characters.
> - NoDecode : such URLs are accepted, but encoded slashes
>   are not decoded but left in their encoded state.

Default is `Off` because letting Apache blindly decodes path separators would expose your machine to **directory traversal** attacks (see [CVE-2007-0450](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2007-0450)), setting this directive to `On` is not safe.

Fortunately, the `NoDecode` option (available since version 2.3.12) allows to accept such URLs without exposing your server, so to fix that and let Drupal handle such requests in 404 or whatever, just add the directive in *httpd.conf* :

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

**Note : Virtual hosts don't inherit this directive from the global context, it's required to reset the directive to the desired value in virtual host container(s), otherwise it will take the default value.**

Now, if you still get a server 404 instead of a drupal 404, that's probably because the directive `ErrorDocument 404` is not taken into account, or is overridden somewhere.

A quick way to check whether or not this directive is actually loaded is precisely to set a static content (by the way in this case there's no input display issue ;) :

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Page not found"
```

Maybe the correct behavior for Apache would be to catch this kind of urls as 403, and to let drupal handle it as well you would set `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php`.

It's also worth noting that the generic drupal 404 "page not found" page can easily be overridden at `admin/config/system/site-information`, as well as the 403 "access denied" page.

Comment: hm, I set it but it's not fixing my issue, issue is still there even without `%2F`, so if you try `https://drupal7.example/.htcaccess/***Attention!***` you'll have the same result where you see `***Attention!***` on server 404 page...

Comment: Well, in this case it's probably because directive `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` is overriden somewhere, if you use vhost for example. I just edited my answer just in case.. Maybe there is something else to catch in your config, you should get apache 403 for these urls, and still be able to handle these with drupal using ErrorDocument directives.

Comment: Awesome, `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php` did the trick. Thanks!